# How can I run Chrome on Google colab?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, google-colaboratory

**How can I run Chrome on Google colab?**

**pip install**

```
1. !pip install selenium
2. !apt-get update
3. !apt install chromium-chromedriver
4. !cp /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver /usr/bin
```

**my sample code**

```
from selenium import webdriver 

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver', options=options)
url = "https://www.instagram.com/" 

driver.get(url)
```

**my purpose**

I want to see Chrome work

`without the options.add_argument('--headless') option..`

[image]